# Python: Get sender of UDP broadcast / socket.recvcmsg() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp, broadcast

I use [`socket.recvmsg()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvmsg) to get the data and the sender's IP address of a UDP broadcast message. This works fine on Linux, but this method is not available on Windows (Python 3.3). How can I obtain the sender's IP address?

```
from socket import *

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
fd.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
fd.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

data, _, _, addr = fd.recvmsg(4096) # <- how to achieve this without recvmsg?
host, upd_port =  addr
```

Comment: Have you checked the Windows firewall?

Comment: @uphill This is not about the connectivity. Of course I can receive the broadcasts with socket.recv(), but the result only contains the UDP payload.

Comment: Do you have a peace of code?

Comment: @uphill See my edit

Comment: I think on Windows, `recvfrom` should work?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis you are right. I always misinterpreted recvfrom to be applicable if we know from where we receive. You can post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in the Python documentation that you linked, that [`recvfrom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) returns similar values to what your code is looking for (bytes, address) and is compatible with Windows

> socket.**[recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom)**(*bufsize*[, *flags*])